# setting event to happen inbetween certain time

Tags: php, mysql

so i have a database that have a set of events that are suppose to happen and end at certain time. So say my table is (the event here is an actual event, not a code thing)

```
Event |  TimeStart  |   TimeEnd   |   Day
A     |     0800    |    1400     |    2
B     |     2000    |    2300     |    3
C     |     1200    |    1900     |    4
```

What i want is that i want the event to occur IF its between the TimeEnd and TimeEnd + 3 hours. The problem that i encounter is what if its 2300? I used the days with date(N) that correspond to monday (1) - Sunday (7)

So if its Event B, i need to have a code that take the current time, reduce it by 3 hours (so that i doesn't go to day 4) then i get the TimeEnd and add on 3 hours to it.

The problem now that i tested is that How do i make Event B to be on Day 3? even if i used strtotime() Event B still shows day 4 after it passed 2400 hour.

To make the matter clearer, i am creating a voting poll that only starts after the event ended and it only last for 3 hours.

Edit found the answer, didn't know using "Monday this week" made sense for date() :D

Answer (score 0):

Your representation of times in the table is kinda weird. If each event will happen only one time (doesn't repeat for instance every monday), I suggest you use [unix timestamp](http://www.unixtimestamp.com/) to represent the times. Then you will have no such problems.

Comment: it does repeat every monday, that's the problem.

Comment: Well in order tho help you, we should know exactly what you are trying to do. Are you making a select and deciding if you should display a poll for some event or not? If so, it should not be a problem to get a timestamp of the start of current/previous day, add the ending time to it + your 30 minutes, and then compare the result to the current date. But I'm just guessing. Perhaps you could provide some code that you have.